# What does "lot" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The passage below comes from *Emily's Runaway Imagination* by Beverly Cleary.

> It would be pleasantly scary if the pioneer ancestors had left a ghost
>   or two around the house, perhaps in the cupola, but these ancestors
>   must have been too busy clearing the land and settling the state of
>   Oregon to participate in any ghostly activities like people in some of
>   the sad old songs Mama sometimes sang. As far as Emily knew, there was
>   not a brokenhearted damsel or a disappointed lover killed in a duel in
>   the **lot**.

I'm not quite certain about the meaning of the boldfaced LOT.
I think it means

> a. A piece of land having specific boundaries, especially one constituting a part of a city, town, or block.
>   http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lot

Am I right?

Comment: Lot refers to a group of people- here, the pioneer ancestors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [the link you provided](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lot), "lot" is not being used as **2a** (a piece of land), but rather **1c**:

> c. A number of associated people or things:
> *placating an angry lot of tenants; kids who were a noisy lot*

---

> As far as Emily knew, there was not a brokenhearted damsel or a disappointed lover killed in a duel in the **lot**.
>
> As far as Emily knew, there was not a brokenhearted damsel or a disappointed lover killed in a duel in the **group of pioneer ancestors**.